# C# WebClient Headers not in the same sort

Tags: c#, http-headers, http-post, webclient

the Code :

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                if (Form1.ProxyEnabled)
                {
                    WebProxy wp = new WebProxy(string.Format("{0}:{1}", PAddress, PPort));
                    if (Form1.AuthenRequired)
                        wp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(PUser, PPass);
                    wc.Proxy = wp;
                }
                ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = ua;
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "en-US,en;q=0.8";
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "*/*";
                wc.Headers.Add("Custom", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

                Uri URI = new Uri("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
                ResultString = wc.UploadString(URI, ss);
            }
```

the Result is :

```
POST /api.php HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Custom: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Length: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Expected Result is :

```
POST /api.php HTTP/1.1
    Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Referer: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
    Accept: */*
    Custom: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Content-Length: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Connection: Keep-Alive
```

So, what happened ? why the headers is not in the same order as I add it and how to fix that ? how to send custom headers in exact order ?

Comment: Order should not make a difference.  Why do you care that the order is different?

Comment: I know that there is no difference and It did worked as it should but I want to make it in the same order for two reasons:
1. It has to emulate the request 100%
2. I just want to know what happened !

Comment: You have to understand that if the order makes no difference, so you DID emulate the request 100%. Simple as this.

Comment: The class library sets the order.  You enable the properties and set the values but you have not control on the order they are sent.   If you really want to change the order you need to use a different library.

Comment: But the other end can check for that and know that it's just a fake request not a real one from a browser. Am I wrong? I think I will go with TcpClient then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with tcpclient and everything is working great.